# track real object movements via vofuria and unity ignoring camera movements

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am developing an augmented reality application that tracks an object via camera (real object, using Vuforia), my aim is to detect the distance it pass.
I am using unity + Vuforia.
For each frame, I calculate the distance between the first position and the current position (Vector calculating).

But I got wrong position/s details, and camera movements affect the result.
(I don't want to take the camera offset in account)
any solution?

for more clearing I want to implement this experience: (video):

https://youtu.be/-c5GiXuATh4

Comment: what do you use as origin in your Camera configuration? Are you checking if the tracking state of your object is `Tracked` all the time

Comment: I was using CAMERA as origin , but if I set the origin as "MY TARGET" I cannot get movements, (when I move the real object and origin =MY TARGET, the position with no change)

Answer (score 1):

From the comments and the question i understood problem is using camera as origin. This means at all frames of your application camera will be origin and the position of all trackables will be calculated relative to camera. Therefore, even though if you do not move your target, it's position will change because of camera movement.

To eliminate this problem i would recommend using extended tracking. This will minimize the impact of camera movement to position of your target. You can try and test this by adding a trail renderer to your image and you will see your image will stay at a certain position regardless of camera movement.